# On the table last entry is coming at the last.I want to show the latest entries on the top of the table. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a form where if a user posts something it will be shown on a table.I am using firebase realtime database for this purpose. Currently the latest entries are showing at the last of the table.I want to show the latest entries at the top of the table.The latest entries should come at the first and old entries should come the last.

```js
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  //mycofig
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("Registrations");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var data = childSnapshot.val();
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref("Registrations").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = "";
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        var val = data.val();
        content += "<tr>";
        content += "<td>" + val.name + "</td>";
        content += "<td>" + val.business + "</td>";
        content += "<td>" + val.phone + "</td>";
        content += "<td>" + val.area + "</td>";
        content += "<td>" + val.category + "</td>";
        content += "</tr>";
      });
      $("#ex-table").append(content);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* Zebra striping */

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  /*
Label the data
*/
  td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "Name";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "Location";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "Rent p/m";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "BHK/Rooms";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content: "Total Persons";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before {
    content: "Phone no";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before {
    content: "Other Details";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before {
    content: "Posting Date";
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<table id="ex-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Business name</th>
      <th>Phone no</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try `data.reverse()`? Are you sorting the data properly in your query? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried data.reverse() , but it shows data is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column-reverse;` will put the latest items of the table to first place. Add this css to the table in which you want the last items to be at first place:

```
#ex-table{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue  is that you are placing the items at the end of the table after the html string is built - as per the following

```
 $("#ex-table").append(content);
```

If you swap that to "prepend" - it will insert the new item at the start of the table as per the following

```
 $("#ex-table").prepend(content);
```

Therefore the last row added to the table with be the first row of the table. Here is a link to the documentation - https://api.jquery.com/prepend/

That said - I would manipulate the data being read and reverse it so that the data matches the order of the expected table.

Comment: 'face-plant ' - oh - of course - you are making the string from all the tr's and then appending- my solution totally won't work  -sorry. - did you try removing the data.reverse(); - if that is reversing the order of the data then it may work if you remove it.